# Php - how to check if a function doesn't provide any response in 30 secs or so

Tags: php

I am using dns_get_record inside a user defined function and do some process inside user defined function.Sometimes dns_get_record takes very long time to process if domain is dead.

Is there a way Php function can return a value if the total process takes more than 30 sec or so. Basically I would like to return control to main program if total user defined function execution time is more than 30 secs. How I can do this in Php?

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176497/limit-execution-time-of-an-function-or-command-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As v2solutions.com suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421401/php-how-to-check-if-a-function-doesnt-provide-any-response-in-30-secs-or-so#comment43286195_27421401), you could use `set_time_limit()` but the whole process would terminate with a fatal error.

On the other hand, you could spawn a new process [with forking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1160192/1446005) or by starting [a 
new process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process/45966#45966) altogether ([alternative option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process/4832703#4832703)), or [a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501449/1446005), and monitor this subprocess/thread from your main loop.